# localhost/~username is not working, gives 404 Not Found error

Tags: php, apache

I am fairly new to server-side web development and am trying to get a local server up and running.  I'm using an apache 2 server on my mac, but can't for the life of me get localhost to give me anything but 404 Not Found error. I'm putting localhost/~ and my username in the search bar and still nothing.  I've been following a lynda.com tutorial to configure my personal site folder and haven't had any luck.

I'm trying to configure a personal site folder, or at least that is the terminology used in the tutorial. I created a "Sites" folder in my home directory.  Then, I put an "index.html" file in the "Sites" folder to test.

After that, I configured a "httpd.conf" file through my terminal by entering "sudo nano/etc/apache2/httpd.conf".  He had me un-comment the following lines:

```
LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
```

After doing this, I exited the file and saved the changes. I then entered into the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
```

Here I uncommented the following line:

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
```

I then entered into the terminal

```
cd /etc/apache2/
```

And then:

```
cd users
```

I entered:

```
sudo nano jacobbryant.conf
```

In this file, I made sure it only contained:

```
<Directory "/Users/jacobbryant/Sites/">
  Options Indexes MultiViews
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I then exited this file and restarted the apache server with:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

After this, I went to my browser and typed in "localhost/~jacobbryant" and got a "404 Not Found" error.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried? It's really unclear what you've been doing and what you're trying to achieve

Comment: updated with more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what @jhilgeman is talking about.  Apache has an extension for Per-user web directories that must be setup in order to map ~username to the home directory specified in the configuration.  It looks like you have enabled the correct extension but missed the `UserDir` directive.

For Example: `UserDir public_html` will serve `/home/myuser/public_html` at http://your.host.tld/~myuser/

For you example, ditch the `<Directory>` and use the `UserDir` directive instead.  Please read over https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html for setup instructions.